# Getting value from Json dictionary in Swift 5

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I am extracting currency values from an online currency service.

After I get a json array of all currencies, I pick 2 currencies to compare.

```
[{
    "symbol": "$",
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "symbol_native": "$",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "rounding": 0,
    "code": "USD",
    "name_plural": "US dollars"
}, {
    "symbol": "CA$",
    "name": "Canadian Dollar",
    "symbol_native": "$",
    "decimal_digits": 2,
    "rounding": 0,
    "code": "CAD",
    "name_plural": "Canadian dollars"
}]
```

I create a query and ship it back to my service.

Query:

```
 let URLString: String =  finalURLPart1 + finalURLPart2 + finalURLPart3 + ""
        
        //print(#function, "URLString: ", URLString)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: URLString)!, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        
        //print(#function, "request: ", request)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okButton)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
               
                // 2- Getting the response (Data)
                if data != nil {
                   
                    do {
                       
                    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                        //Async
                       
                        print(jsonResponse)
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                          
                            if let rates = jsonResponse["rates"] as? [String : Any] {
                                
                               
                                
                                for convertedValue in rates.values {
                                    print("convertedValue: ", convertedValue)
                                    print("Type: ", type(of: convertedValue))
                                    
                                    
                                
                                }
                                
                                }
                            }
                            
                        
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("Error")
                    }
                    }
                
                
            }
        }
       
        // 3- Process the data (Parsing: or JSON Serialization)
        task.resume() // starting the task
        //semaphore.wait()
       
        
    }
```

I get this back:

```
["base": BAM, "date": 2020-10-13 22:18:00+00, "rates": {
    BDT = "51.11942821250704";
}]
```

```
for convertedValue in rates.values {
      print("convertedValue: ", convertedValue)
      print("Type: ", type(of: convertedValue))
}
```

The output is:

```
convertedValue:  51.11942821250704
Type:  __NSCFString
```

How can I get the float value of convertedValue?

Comment: please edit your question and post the JSON string received and format your post properly

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the formatting..

Comment: the value you get back is not a valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can get the value of `BDT` key from the `rates` JSON object, cast it is as it's type (which is `String`) and then convert it to `Float` using `init?(_:)` initializer:

```
if let rates = jsonResponse["rates"] as? [String: Any] {
    if let stringValue = rates.values.first as? String, let convertedValue = Float.init(stringValue) {
        print("convertedValue:", convertedValue)
        print("Type:", type(of: convertedValue))
    }
}
```

This will print:

> ```
> convertedValue: 51.119427
> Type: Float
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The  `stringValue = rates["BDT"] ` is a problem as each currency has it's own code (eg "BDT")

Comment: @ICT1901 you can use `rates.values.first` if there is always only one key in `rates` object. I updated my answer.